# how to run as a nobody account?

Tags: permissions, centos, centos-6

I'm currently using CentOS 6 on a VPS (openVZ).

I just created a user `stunnel_user` and group `stunnel_grp` to run `stunnel` on some `nobody:nogroup`.

I changed the shell of the `stunnel_user` to `/sbin/nologin`  to make it safe.

But after changing the users's shell, whenever I try to run the command as `stunnel_user` (in root!) using:

```
runuser -l stunnel_user -c stunnel
sudo -u stunnel_user -c stunnel
```

or editing the `stunnel.conf` file to have:

```
setuid=stunnel_user
setgid=stunnel_grp
```

I get:

> "this account is currently not available"

(also, I tried using 
`su --shell=/bin/bash --session-command="stunnel" stunnel_user`,
but this exits immediately)

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that account is locked, /var/log/secure may hold answers. 
If reading through PAM configs isn't your idea of fun,
a easy fix to try is just to set a password on the account.